# Notifications when application is is background;

Tags: ios, notifications

I have already

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    if ( application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive )
        // app was already in the foreground
    else
        // app was just brought from background to foreground
    ...
}
```

Now is that possible that I perform some some set of action when notification arrive, keeping the application in background; I don't want to bring my app at foreground when notification is received; What I want is when notifications arrive, I just set some flags and (app is still in background) and when user open the app himself, he/she can view the message in some graceful way;
Summary: I don't want to bring the application in foreground when notifications arrives, but want to perform some actions in my code keeping the app in background;

Thanks;

Comment: It's not possible to start a background task while in background. There only a few things that can run in background on iOS. Like: GPS tracking and sound playback. The rules are very strict about background tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

Since your app is in the background it won't know anything about the incoming notifications. The notification is taken care of by iOS.

However, when your app opens due to a user swiping/tapping the notifications your app will get the **launchOptions** passed in the above method. If the user opens the app directly (tapping the app icon) the **launchOptions** will be empty. See the [UIApplicationDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) for more details.

To retrieve remote notification payload you can do:

```
[launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey]
```

for the local notification payload you can do:

```
[launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey]
```